# Air ionizer current transformer

Tags: current, current-transformer

believe is a current transformer from air ionizer can somebody help me tell me what this thing might do I think it turns 110 into something less

P48A14-c/t only markings I see on it without opening it up I know you don't know what the winding numbers are came out of an air ionizer. A really old one think it was called airozone

Comment: for one, show us a photo! for two, I can't think of any reason an ionizer would use a current transformer.

Comment: I'd say it's a voltage transformer but apparently OP is not a native English speaker.

Comment: To ionize air you are going to require a high voltage, so if that is the transformer's purpose  it would likely be to step up the voltage. Of course the stepping up could be done in another part of the circuit and the transformer may only be for the psu section. Hard to guess without a photo of the overall circuit board or a circuit diagram.